# Conditional decrementation on a pandas series / dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, series

How do I change the value inside a series/dataframe like so:

```py
labels = df_known["labels"] # get dataframe

for label in labels:
    for c in classes_to_remove:
        if label > c:
            label -= 1 # doesn't actually change the label in the series, just the local variable
```

This decrements every label by the number of classes removed, that are smaller than the label.

For example, if `classes_to_remove = [1, 3]` and `labels = [0, 2, 4]` I would decrement `4` twice, because it's bigger than both `3` and `1`,decrement `2` just once, as it is only bigger than `1` and keep `0` unchanged. In the end `labels = [0, 1, 2]`

Edit:

Example:
`classes_to_remove = [2]`

The dataframe:

```
labels
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
        ..
20596    6
20597    6
20598    6
20599    6
20600    6
Name: labels, Length: 15497, dtype: int64

np.unique(labels)
array([0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int64) # notice 2 is missing
```

expected dataframe:

```
np.unique(labels)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Will you please send a sample of your dataframe? It's so much easy to visualize.

Comment: Also your expected output.

Comment: I added as per your request. My main issue is mostly that `label -= 1` doesn't actually change the series, but the local variable. I'm not entirely sure how to fix that.

Comment: For this particular case, you can simply do this: `df[df > 2] -= 1`. Will that work?

Comment: The `classes_to_remove` is going to be different every iteration, including multiple numbers not just of size 1 - so it could include both 2 and 5, for instance.

Comment: Though so, let me see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.greater.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) to compare the `labels` with `classes_to_remove`, then `sum` the resulting boolean mask along `axis=1` and subtract this sum from `labels` column to get the result

```
labels -= np.greater.outer([*labels], classes_to_remove).sum(1)
```

Details:

1. Here `np.greater.outer` is used to compare each label to every number in `classes_to_remove`

```
>>> np.greater.outer([*labels], classes_to_remove)

array([[False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

2. Now, we sum the boolean mask obtain in the previous step along the axis=1

```
>>> np.greater.outer([*labels], classes_to_remove).sum(1)

array([0, 1, 2])
```

3. Subtract the calculated sum from labels to get the result

```
>>> labels - np.greater.outer([*labels], classes_to_remove).sum(1)

0    0
1    1
2    2
Name: labels, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works a bit more? I'm a bit confused about what this line is actually doing.

Comment: @IM  Sure, I've edited the answer.